# Dynamically altering rowspan in a table with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a table when users can merge rows and columns. I've got the code for columns working OK, and rows are almost there too - however, when I alter a rowspan from 3 down to 2, I get an extra column added.

You can see what I mean in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mojj9vvv/25/).

And here's my code:

```
function growRow(td, span, cell_content) {
  var cell_content = (typeof cell_content === 'undefined') ? '<td></td>' : cell_content
  var row = td.closest("tr")
  var index = td.index()
  var old_span = (typeof td.attr('rowspan') === 'undefined') ? 1 : Number(td.attr('rowspan'))
  var table = row.parents('table')
  var content

  td.attr('rowspan', span)

  if (span > old_span) {
    // If we want to merge cells, this is easy
    var selector = "tr:lt(" + (span - 1) + ")"

    row.nextAll(selector).each(function () {
        // Grab the content from each cell
      content = $("td:eq(" + index + ")", $(this)).html()
      $("td:eq(" + index + ")", $(this)).remove()
    })

    // Get the next cell down
    row = $('tr:eq('+ span +')')
    // Append the content to make it look as though the cells are 'moving down'
    row.find('td:eq('+ index +')').html(content)
  } else {
    // This is where I'm having problems
    // Get the number of cells we need to put back
    count = old_span - span
    // Work through the rows
    for (var i=0; i < count ; i++) {
      // Get the row at the right index
      r = $(row.nextAll()[i])
      if (index == 0) {
      // If we're at the beginning of a row, we need to prepend
        r.prepend(cell_content)
      } else {
      // Otherwise use nth-child to append in the right place
        r.find('td:nth-child(' + index + ')').after(cell_content)
      }
    }
  }

  return td
}
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated, as I've been on this for DAYS now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to get the row at `r + count` offset? Rather than just `r`?

Comment: Yep, that's got it. All I needed to do was get the offset (span - 1) and add it to the index. Works perfectly now! https://jsfiddle.net/mojj9vvv/26/